# How to re-map Iterm2 Ctrl+L and Ctrl+D to Cmd+L and Cmd+D

Tags: terminal, iterm2

Migrating from Ubuntu to Mac, my muscle memory is to use `Ctrl+L` and `Ctrl+D` to `clear screen` and `exit shell` for `bash`

Using iTerm2, I repeatedly press `Cmd+L` and `Cmd+D` which either doesn't have any effect or I end up splitting the screen.

How do I map these to `Cmd+L` and `Cmd+D` to achieve the same ? Also `Cmd+C` to abort an ongoing action

Also, the `fn+C` keeps opening the `control center`, whenever I mistakenly press that combination instead of `Ctrl+C`. How do I stop that ?

Comment: Try the method for remapping that is explained in [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388694/452951). If it works for you, I will put up an answer.

Comment: Yup !! Swapping `cmd` and `ctrl` seems to work for L/D/C options. What should I do with the `fn+C` opening the control center ?

Comment: I wrote an answer on that part. Which key is Fn?

Comment: The `globe/fn` key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post
[In iTerm2 map the left Command key to the left Control key & map Command+Tab](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388692/in-iterm2-map-the-left-command-key-to-the-left-control-key-map-commandtab)
contains an
[answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/388694/452951)
that demonstrates how key mappings are done in MacOS.

This is done in iTerm's *Preferences → Keys → Remap Modifiers*,
where the actions of modifiers like Ctrl and Cmd can be mapped:

[image]